# Display rich club results in R console

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory

[image: snap shot of R console]
I am using R to do rich club coefficient analysis. I get rich club network, but some of the edges are omitted in the R console. How do I get all the edges in the network. The result shows 4 lists, 1 list with rich cluster coefficient value, edges (some are omitted), number of edges and number of nodes.

Thanks

Priya

Comment: You are not a new user, you should know that we need a code and data example. Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.) And **the code you have used**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(E(rich_club[["graph"]]), full = TRUE)` (see `?E` and `?print.igraph.es`) is going to show all the edges:

```
g <- make_ring(50)
print(E(g), full = TRUE)
# + 50/50 edges from cf330f3:
#  [1]  1-- 2  2-- 3  3-- 4  4-- 5  5-- 6  6-- 7  7-- 8  8-- 9  9--10
# [10] 10--11 11--12 12--13 13--14 14--15 15--16 16--17 17--18 18--19
# [19] 19--20 20--21 21--22 22--23 23--24 24--25 25--26 26--27 27--28
# [28] 28--29 29--30 30--31 31--32 32--33 33--34 34--35 35--36 36--37
# [37] 37--38 38--39 39--40 40--41 41--42 42--43 43--44 44--45 45--46
# [46] 46--47 47--48 48--49 49--50  1--50
```

Comment: @ Julius. I tried E(rich_club[["graph"]], still edges are omitted

Comment: @ Julius, I tried as_ids(E), I got the entire list. Thank you

Comment: @Priya, right, I missed that `E` still does the omission by default. I updated my answer: `print(E(rich_club[["graph"]]), full = TRUE)` shows edges in this more intuitive and perhaps preferred way.

Comment: @Priya, I guess the answer can be accepted then, if it answers your question.